Background location enabled for my app, play store rejected my app update. How to fix?
I am building a food delivery app in flutter, where it contains seller side, user side and driver side.
The app contains live tracking feature, which requires background location permission. But this leads to the rejection of the app. The foreground service location permission is required for android 14 to work for the background location.
This is the mail for rejection reason which I got from google.:

Issue found: Background location access not declared
We detected that your app contains at least one feature that requests access to location in the background, however your permission declaration form did not reflect this. Please log in to your Play Console to resubmit your location declaration form. You may either remove location in the background from your app or indicate that the usage is in the background.
Issue details
We found an issue in the following area(s):
Version code 26
About the Permissions and APIs that Access Sensitive Information policy
Requests for permission and APIs that access sensitive information should make sense to users. You may only request permissions and APIs that access sensitive information that are necessary to implement critical current features or services in your app that are promoted in your Google Play listing. You may not use permissions or APIs that access sensitive information that give access to user or device data for undisclosed, unimplemented, or disallowed features or purposes. Personal or sensitive data accessed through permissions or APIs that access sensitive information may never be sold nor shared for a purpose facilitating sale.
Request permissions and APIs that access sensitive information to access data in context (via incremental requests), so that users understand why your app is requesting the permission. Use the data only for purposes that the user has consented to. If you later wish to use the data for other purposes, you must ask users and make sure they affirmatively agree to the additional uses.*

This is my manifest.xml where all the location related permission is mentioned.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>

Now How can I  make the app approve? I am using Location package.
Future<void> _listenLocation() async {
  model.location.enableBackgroundMode(enable: true);
  locationStream = model.location.onLocationChanged.listen((event) async {
    logger.w("Is it Working.....");
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('location')
        .doc(widget.orderId.toString())
        .set({
      'latitude': event.latitude,
      'longitude': event.longitude,
      'dishOrderId': widget.orderId.toString()
    }, SetOptions(merge: true));
  });
}

This function is require for continuous updating of Driver location when the app is in background and google map is opened. But the catch is the location permission is in all time. Please tell me way to fix.
This is the message what we are passing for getting the background location permission in dialog box:

We need your permission to track your device's location for accurate delivery of order.  You can manage this permission in your device settings at any time.

This is the video link which we added to play console:
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/6X3VeCxIcfQ
I have tried follow youtube videos to make the live tracking work but this requires background location. I don't find any way to make the live tracking work with foreground location only in flutter. any help will be appreciated.

"But this leads to the rejection of the app." What reason do the reviewers give for rejecting your app? If possible, copy/paste their explanation into your question - as that likely explains what part of what you're doing violates their guidelines.

Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?

@FrankvanPuffelen brother I have re edited the question with all you need can you please tell me now how to fix and get approaved ???

check this stackoverflow answer, maybe there's an old apk that you uploaded before to play store caused the problem

@gopelkujo sir I need backgorund location permission to make my app work

"We detected that your app contains at least one feature that requests access to location in the background, however your permission declaration form did not reflect this." From that it sounds like you didn't specify that the app uses background location when in a form when you submitted the app.

I think, you dont need ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission.
I assume, you use something like flutter_foreground_task or pigeon for fetching location in an android foreground service.
Your foreground serivce location fetching does NOT count as background.
ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION is created for WorkManagers/Alarm to do it actually in background when app was not even launched. Foreground services launched from the app don't need this permission.
So, if driver presses "GO" button and you start a service with a notification it counts as foreground.
https://developer.android.com/develop/sensors-and-location/location/background
Permissions you should use
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />

Here is also a sample of foreground location.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task

Hey can you provide a sample for foreground service and Manifest that which permission I can use for that.

You have correct permissions, just remove background location permission

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required#location   in this link there is clear instruction for foreground location service type that you need background location information

Yeah, but I shared a link where it's stated that foreground services don't need it :)

"For this reason, you cannot create a location foreground service while your app is in the background, unless you've been granted the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION runtime permission."
You cannot create a location foreground service while your app is in the background, but you create a location foreground service in foreground, from running FlutterActivity
